# Android How to set my app as default sms app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an app that accesses my call logs and sms logs and shows my monthly usage.

Is there any way to use READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG permission from other than setting it as default phone app?

I want to show sms history using READ_SMS permission, but should I set it as default text app like READ_CALL_LOG permission?

If so, please tell me how. I already set it as default phone, but I don't know how to set it as default sms app.

Like implementing InCallService to set the default calling app, what do I need to do to set it as the default sms app?

I added the necessary code to the manifest, and the Fragment requested to set it as the default sms app, but the default sms setting dialog popup does not appear.

```html
<activity
        android:name=".presentation.main.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>


<receiver
  android:name=".receiver.SmsReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".service.BaseSmsService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

      <data android:scheme="sms" />
      <data android:scheme="smsto" />
      <data android:scheme="mms" />
      <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
  android:name=".receiver.MmsReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
      <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

```html
Fragment.kt
private fun requestDefaultSmsApp() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val roleManager =
            requireContext().getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
        val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)
        _requestDefaultSmsApp.launch(intent)
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT).apply {
            putExtra(
                Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                requireContext().packageName
            )
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

private val Context.isDefaultSmsApp: Boolean
        get() = packageName == Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this)
```

thank you!